# MetadataType doesn't recognize IgnoreDataMemberAttribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, metadata, metadatatype

I have an entity which is auto generated by `Entity Framework` from database

```
public partial class Demand : Entity
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DemandUserComment> DemandUserComments { get; set; }
}
```

then added A `MetadataType` to add `DataContract` and `DataMemeber` attributes to that Entity (independent of Db changes).

```
[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
internal class DemandMetaData
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<DemandUserComment> DemandUserComments { get; set; }
}
[MetadataType(typeof (DemandMetaData))]
public partial class Demand
{
}
```

but the `[IgnoreDataMember]` doesn't apply to `Demand` how can I handle it?

Comment: I have the very same issue, did you figure how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use `[NotMapped]` attribute. See the [NotMappedAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: While this answer may theoretically answer the question, [it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259), and provide the link for reference. Please add the relevant content directly to your answer, as it'll prevent link rot.

Comment: @Joseph - I believe `[NotMapped]` answers the question. The link is just a citation. Considering its from MSDN, the link probably won't disappear anytime soon (it may move, but that's a different story...).

Comment: Sorry both of you, this is not the answer. As far as I know, NotMapped is to tell EF that the objective Property should not be mapped to the DataBase. This is not the case. I think Mohsen and I have the same problem, we need to expose our EF through WCF, but we do not want to serialize the virtual properties (Navigating Properties). This should work, but for some reason, the WCF server is ignoring the Metadata declaration. You can see my 3 tries on this subject. [Try1](http://pho.to/7Fh50/g1), [Try2](http://pho.to/7Fh50/4n), [Try3](http://pho.to/7Fh50/lm)